# Why does the following two commands of ps give different `CMD` field?

Tags: ps

Why does the following two commands of ps give different `CMD` field? It matters because `screen` and `SCREEN` are different: the first is client and the second is server. Thanks.

```
$ ps -A | grep -i screen
 3341 ?        00:00:00 screen
 3875 ?        00:00:00 screen
27525 ?        00:00:00 screen
$ ps -Af | grep -i screen
testme    3341     1  0  2018 ?        00:00:00 SCREEN -S testme
testme    3875     1  0  2018 ?        00:00:00 SCREEN -S tm
t        27525     1  0  2018 ?        00:00:00 SCREEN -S test
```

`SCREEN` is not a program, and then why is it showed in `ps`?

```
$ SCREEN
SCREEN: command not found
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`screen` renames its main (server) process `SCREEN` to distinguish it from later clients.

This is very obliquely mentioned once in the man page:

> Note         that  this command only affects debugging output from the main "SCREEN"         process correctly. Debug output from attacher  processes  can  only  be         turned off once and forever.

but, oddly, not explicitly mentioned anywhere I can see.

`ps` and `ps -f` display different things for CMD: the executable name (`ps`, the "command" format specifier) and the reconstructed command line (`ps -f`, the "args" format specifier). The latter uses the process's ARGV and sees changes to it, while the executable name itself is unchanged.

Comment: Thanks. What is the API function which allows a process to change its name?

Comment: There/s no function, you just update the argument array.

Comment: Do you mean the screen program changes the values of the elements in its `argv` array?  The change is internal to  the screen program, so how can it be visible to `ps`?

Comment: `hexdump -C /proc/self/cmdline`

Comment: Does the linux kernel read and update the values in argv array in /proc/self/cmdline, when a program changes them internally?

Comment: It would seem so.

Comment: @Tim Reading from `/proc/self/cmdline` effectively reads the argv array from inside the program each time.  The kernel does not keep a second copy of the arguments, so there is nothing to update.  It is very similar to using `gdb` to debug the program and view the current contents of the array.

Comment: When running a python script in shell as command `./sleep.py`, does python interpreter modify the value in argv[0] to be `/usr/bin/python3`? See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/498244/how-is-a-windows-executable-file-run-via-wine

Comment: It already says that, so it doesn't need to modify it.

Comment: What do you mean by "It already says that"? The command to run the script is `./sleep.py`, not `/usr/bin/python3 ./sleep.py`

Comment: " `ps -f ` uses the process's ARGV and sees changes to it, while `ps` sees the executable name which itself is unchanged." Is the executable name stored somewhere (the first argument to `execve()`?), how does `ps` find it out?

Comment: Am I correct that when running `./sleep.py`, there will be two calls to `execve()`. The first call treats the script as an executable and fails, and the second call to `execve()` actually with the same arguments as when running a command `/usr/bin/python3 ./sleep.py`

Comment: @Tim you’ve asked similar questions before, the answers to which explained how scripts are run — see [What is the actual command executed when running a script with a shebang as its name with same arguments?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/387304/86440) for example.

Comment: Similarly bash login shells will show as "bash" or "-bash" depending on the ps `command` vs `args` output format specifier.

Answer (score 4):

## They do not.

So strictly speaking a question asking *why* they do is unanswerable, it taking a falsehood as its premise.

They show the `cmd` and the `ucmd` columns, two *different* pieces of information.  Unfortunately, both the GNU `ps` program and the FreeBSD `ps` program make things quite confusing here.

Kernels such as Linux and the kernels of the BSDs provide four (relevant) pieces of information about a process, via files in `/proc` and `sysctl()`:

- its program image short name, a.k.a. the short name used for process accounting;
- its argument strings, initialized by `execve()` and modifiable at runtime;
- its environment strings, initialized by `execve()` and modifiable at runtime; and
- the full pathname of its executable program image file.

The argument strings and environment strings are modifiable at runtime in ways that I covered in https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/438007/5132 and https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/432681/5132 .  Linux also permits modifying the process accounting name.

GNU Screen has modified its argument strings, so that the first one reads "SCREEN", but not its process accounting name, which remains as "screen".

There are just two columns for displaying these four pieces of information in `ps`.  In the FreeBSD `ps`, the columns comprise this information as follows:

- The column named by `command` and `args` comprises the argument strings, plus the environment strings if the `e` option is used, plus the accounting name in square brackets if it does not match the first of the argument strings; all prefixed with a tree diagram if the `d` option is used and it is the last column.
- The column named by `ucomm` and `comm` comprises the process accounting name.

The GNU `ps` adds `cmd` as an alias for the former and `ucmd` as an alias for the latter.  It puts the tree diagram and environment strings in *both* columns, and always puts the tree diagram in even if the column is *not* the last column.

With GNU `ps`, the `-f` option (not to be confused with the `f` option) in the `-Af` in the question is simply a shorthand for specifying a different set of columns for `ps` to print.  The default set of columns includes `ucmd`.  The set used when the `-f` option is used includes `cmd` instead.

The manual for BSD `ps` lays this out explicitly, giving the exact columns selected by its `-j`, `-l`, `-u`, and `-v` shorthands.  The manual for GNU `ps` mentions "full format", "jobs format", "long format", and "user format" but does not explicitly list which set of columns each one is.

To further the confusion, both the GNU `ps` and the FreeBSD `ps` do not use the column names used on the command line, in the column headings given in their outputs.  So one often cannot tell from the column heading alone which column is actually being displayed.

- FreeBSD `ps` labels the accounting name column either `UCOMM` or `COMMAND`, but also labels the argument strings column `COMMAND`.
- GNU `ps` labels the argument strings column either `CMD` or `COMMAND`, but also labels the accounting name column either `CMD` or `COMMAND`.

(Laurent Bercot's `s6-ps`, for comparison, has just `comm`, `args`, and `env`, with fixed and distinct header labels `COMM`, `COMMAND`, and `ENVIRONMENT`, giving just the first three of the four pieces of information from the kernel directly, without combining them.)

- Laurent Bercot (2014). [`s6-ps`](http://skarnet.org./software/s6-linux-utils/s6-ps.html). *s6-linux-utils*.  Software.

Comment: I'm not aware that GNU has a `ps` command. I think you're actually referring to the `procps`/`procps-ng` implementation.

Comment: It's the GNU-licensed one, as distinguished from the one with the FreeBSD licence.   The situation is already complex to explain.  I am reluctant to make it further complicated by adding an irrelevant tangent about software authorship and licences, or cluttering it with long winded descriptions.  This answer is about the columns.  Short "GNU" and "FreeBSD" attributions are clear enough, especially since the questioner already knows what `ps` xe is using, any clarification of which point belongs in the question.

Comment: busybox is also licensed under the GNU GPL, I don't see how the license has any relevance on the implementation here. Why don't you call is `procps ps`? GNU screen is (now back) in the GNU project. procps is not.

Comment: Thanks. Can you be more specific about "Kernels such as Linux and the kernels of the BSDs provide four (relevant) pieces of information about a process, via files in /proc and sysctl()"? Which file in /proc and which arguments to sysctl() provide each of the four pieces of information?

Comment: The "GNU"/"BSD" attribution is the terminology _from the manual page of the very GNU `ps` program under discussion_ M. Chazelas.  Take it up with its authors.

Comment: @JdeBP where? in this version? https://gitlab.com/procps-ng/procps/blob/master/ps/ps.1

Comment: There are 9 attributive uses of "BSD" in that document.  As I said, take it up with the question (whose lack of identification of the `ps` program you have not queried _at all_) and with the authors of the manual, and stop mucking about here.

Comment: @JdeBP, all I see in that man page is references to GNU style of options (`--option`). Again, procps `ps` is not GNU `ps`, it's not maintained by the FSF, it's not part of the GNU project. Calling it GNU ps is as wrong as calling it Microsoft `ps` just because it does run on PCs with a Windows key on the keyboard.

Comment: @ JdeBP Is "program image short name, a.k.a. the short name used for process accounting" modifiable at runtime?

Comment: "its environment strings, initialized by execve() and modifiable at runtime", I found it is not modifiable at runtime. See `man proc` which says "If, after an execve(2), the process modifies its environment
              (e.g., by calling functions such as putenv(3) or modifying the
              environ(7) variable directly), this file will not reflect
              those changes."

Answer (score 2):

`ps -A` uses the default format, which shows the pid, terminal, cumulated CPU time, and the executable name (`ucmd`). The executable name is not modifiable, and reflects exactly the name of the executable used.

`ps -Af` uses the full format, which among other fields, shows the full command with arguments (`comm`, or `args`). The full command is modifiable, and as explained in [Michael Homer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/73093/michael-homer)’s [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/492314/86440), `screen` modifies it to show whether the process is a client or a server.

To find `screen` processes and determine their purpose, use

```
ps -fC screen
```

This shows the full details of processes whose executable name matches `screen`.