# Which files in `/proc` provides the following information?

Tags: linux, proc

From https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/492346/674

> Kernels such as Linux and the kernels of the BSDs provide four
>   (relevant) pieces of information about a process, via files in `/proc`
>   and `sysctl()`:
>
> - its program image short name, a.k.a. the short name used for process accounting;
> - its argument strings, initialized by `execve()` and modifiable at runtime;
> - its environment strings, initialized by `execve()` and modifiable at runtime; and
> - the full pathname of its executable program image file.

Which file in `/proc` (and which arguments to `sysctl()`) provide each of the four pieces of information?
Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### On Linux:

> - its program image short name, a.k.a. the short name used for process accounting;

```
/proc/<pid>/comm
```

> - its argument strings, initialized by execve() and modifiable at runtime;

```
/proc/<pid>/cmdline
```

> - its environment strings, initialized by execve() and modifiable at runtime; and

```
/proc/<pid>/environ
```

> - the full pathname of its executable program image file.

```
/proc/<pid>/exe
```

(which is a symbolic link to the file).

Additional technical detail for these files can be found in [`man 5 proc`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html).

### On FreeBSD:

> - its program image short name, a.k.a. the short name used for process accounting;

- `sysctl()` with `CTL_KERN`, `KERN_PROC`, and `KERN_PROC_ALL`/`KERN_PROC_PROC` OIDs.
- Dumpable with `sysctl -x kern.proc.all`
- One of the fields in `/proc/PID/status`.
- (if compatibility is installed) one of the fields in `/compat/linux/proc/PID/status`.

> - its argument strings, initialized by execve() and modifiable at runtime;

- `sysctl()` with `CTL_KERN`, `KERN_PROC`, and `KERN_PROC_ARGS` OIDs.
- Also `/proc/PID/cmdline`.
- (if compatibility is installed) `/compat/linux/proc/PID/cmdline`.

> - its environment strings, initialized by execve() and modifiable at runtime; and

- `sysctl()` with `CTL_KERN`, `KERN_PROC`, and `KERN_PROC_ENV` OIDs.
- (if compatibility is installed) `/compat/linux/proc/PID/environ`.

> - the full pathname of its executable program image file.

- `/proc/PID/file` (which is a symbolic link to the file).
- (if compatibility is installed) `/compat/linux/proc/PID/exe`.